# Narrowing Regex results

Tags: html, regex, html-parsing

I'm creating a regex. This is my test dataset:

```
<a href="test.html">test1</a>
<a href="test.pdf">test2</a>
<a href="test.html">test1</a>
<a href="test.html">test1</a><a href="testtime.pdf">test2</a>
```

I'm trying to capture from "href=" to "pdf", but the following regex:

```
href=.*?\.pdf
```

Will capture the right data if it is isolated to one line, but it will also match the following from the last line:

```
href="test.html">test1</a><a href="testtime.pdf
```

I only want from the last "href" to the ".pdf", I don't want the first "href" on the line or anything that comes between it and the second "href". Is it possible to modify the regex to match this properly?

Thanks.

Comment: You want the name of the last linked file only if it's a PDF?

Comment: regex for javascript?

Comment: Please note that parsing HTML with regexes is fraught with peril.  See http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html for examples of why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the attribute to start with a quote and the value not contain this quote:

```
href="[^"]*?\.pdf
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/UuRin3/1

P.S.

[Don't use Regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: This helped me out, thanks.

By the way, I am not using Regex to parse HTML. I am trying to find instances of linked PDFs on a site with 9000 HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use capturing groups, they allow you match whole word, but extract only part of it, for example `href=\"(.*\.pdf)\"` should allow you to match the `href="xxxx.pdf"` string, but extract only `xxxx.pdf` part.

How you do this depends on what technology you use to fetch Regex. Somehow I doubt this is html.